# Construct BST from given preorder traversal?

Tags: java, algorithm

This question is from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-bst-from-given-preorder-traversa/

I can think of below simple algorithm(kind of same that java internally follows for TreeMap)

1. We can start adding the node  one by one. While adding start comparing each node with root node and then decide right/left location
2. Do it recursively

But i do not see mention of it anywhere on google or same link.Per mine understanding it's time complexity will be nlog(n). I understand its not better than second approach which is O(n) but better than first one which is O(n^2) Is not it ?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640382/bst-from-preorder-by-just-inserting-the-nodes-in-same-order discusses the same method as you mentioned. As told in answer this will take nolg(n).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that its better than first approach but second approach is even better as time complexity is O(n).

The approach you suggested will better when you don't have complete input in advance but when you have complete input ready then you don't have to add it one by one which involves finding location of each node (logn). So for n nodes it will be nlog(n)